# Is there a way to control which repositories Leiningen will search by default?

Tags: clojure, repository, leiningen

When you run Leiningen search without a project, it attempts to download the repository index from http://repo1.maven.org and clojars.org.    Is there any way I can pass in an environment variable to download this index from the repository manager instead of these central repositories?

I already use Maven for several builds and I have a settings.xml file that defines my repository as a global mirror.  I see that Leiningen uses Maven settings when it is trying to get Proxy configuration, but it doesn't use this same configuration for downloading the index files.

I want to download the repository index from my repository manager because it would only take a few seconds.  (Download the index from Central takes a very long time.)   Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is planned for the 2.0.0 release of Leiningen: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/281

You can do something like this on a per-project basis by setting :omit-default-repositories true and specifying your mirror in :repositories, (lein search checks :repositories when it's in a project) but there is no way to do it globally yet. Definitely want to get this working as it is a common complaint.

Comment: Oh, I see you are planning to move to Aether.   Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yeah, actually the move to Aether has happened in the 2.0.0-preview series; it's already fairly widely used.

Comment: Still no way to set :omit-default-repositories globally as of lein 2.3.3, right? I tried but failed.

Answer (score 1):

check https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/preview/doc/DEPLOY.md

starting from Private Repositories

is that what you want?

Comment: I think I missed the part where you said that it doesn't work for index only. The thing above is probably not what you're looking for.